# what's the different between refreshObject:mergeChanges: and set object to nil?

Tags: ios, core-data

if I use the method

```
[moc refreshObject:employee mergeChanges:NO];
```

, employee is turned into a fault and any pending changes are lost. but I think I can do it by setting employee to nil, I don't know what's the difference between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`employee = nil` sets only your pointer to the managed object to `nil`, but does not reset the object in the managed object context at all.